# Update more than one phone number contact

Tags: android, android-contentprovider, android-contacts, contactscontract

I need to update more than one phone number for the same contact. I can update only one phone number, but I don't know how I can update 2 for example

Here is my code...

```
String stEtPhone = etPhone.getText().toString();

values.clear();
String phoneWhere = ContactsContract.Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID + "=? AND " + ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE + "=?";
String[] phoneWhereParams = new String[]{String.valueOf(idContacto),ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE};
values.put(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER,stEtPhone);
cr.update(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI, values, phoneWhere, phoneWhereParams);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code should update every row that matches your `WHERE` clause.  If you know there are extra rows that should be matching but aren't, then something is wrong there.

One possible way to test:  You might first want to query for things that match `ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER` for the given `ContactsContract.Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID` and see how many things are returned.

If necessary (though I'm not sure how precisely this is different than what you're already doing), iterate over your results `while(cursor.moveToNext())` and if the phone number matches the one you're trying to update, `update` it.

Note that this is untested, off-the-cuff code, so there are probably small bugs, and that if you were doing this for real you would want to use a `List<ContentProviderOperation>` and then do a batch operation, instead of doing this one by one.

```
ContentResolver resolver = getContentResolver();
String[] columnsToReturn = {Data._ID, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER}
// This should return all of the phone numbers that match your criteria
Cursor cursor = resolver.query(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI, columnsToReturn, phoneWhere, phoneWhereParams, null);

while(cursor != null && cursor.moveToNext()){
    // This code doesn't do this, but you might want to see how many items 
    // are returned in your cursor here to verify that you're getting what 
    // you should for some known case..

    // I'm using the row ID here (Data._ID) to update, instead of your initial WHERE
    resolver.update(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI, values, Data._ID + "=?", cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnId(Data._ID));

}
```

It should not even be necessary to perform the query first, if you get everything set up correctly in your `UPDATE` statement.

You may also find the chunk of code attached to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6433924/grab-multiple-number-from-an-android-contact) question useful.

Comment: But how i can do the update Jon? We can show me a example? :)